# Dismiss UIPopoverController from a button within its UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

This is firstPopoverViewController.h code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface firstPopoverViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

This is my firstPopoverViewController.m code:

```
#import "firstPopoverViewController.h"

@interface firstPopoverViewController ()

@end

@implementation firstPopoverViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(300, 290);

    // Header label
    UILabel *h1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 85)];
    h1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"myFont" size:22.0];
    h1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    h1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    h1.text = @"Heading";
    h1.numberOfLines = 0;
    h1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    // Ok button BG View
    UIView *buttonBG = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300-75, 300, 75)];
    buttonBG.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    // Ok button
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(300/2-130/2, 290-35-15, 130, 35);
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [button setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(closePop) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted=YES;

    // Adding views
    [self.view addSubview:h1];
    [self.view addSubview:buttonBG];
    [self.view addSubview:button];

}

-(void)closePop {

}

@end
```

Then there's ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "firstPopoverViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *popButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) firstPopoverViewController *firstPopoverViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *firstPopover;

@end
```

And finally ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /* ##### UIPopController stuff ##### */
    UIImage *popButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"];
    _popButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _popButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 73, 66);
    [_popButton addTarget:self action:@selector(openPop) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    _popButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted=NO;
    [_popButton setImage:popButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.view addSubview:_popButton];

}

-(void)openPop {

    if (_firstPopoverViewController == nil) {
        //Create the _firstPopoverViewController.
        _firstPopoverViewController = [[firstPopoverViewController alloc] init];
    }

    if (_firstPopover == nil) {
        _firstPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_firstPopoverViewController];
        _firstPopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 290);
        [_firstPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0,0, 73, 66) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"show");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"dismiss");
        [_firstPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        _firstPopover = nil;
    }
}

@end
```

It's pretty basic code that displays a button and when I click this button it shows popover. I want to close this popover using button that's inside firstPopoverViewControll.m file. There's a closePop{} method, what should I put inside it to close this popover? Thanks.

By the way I'm beginner as you can see, I researched stackoverflow and there are some solutions with delegates, which seems to be working for others, but didn't work for me, could you please show me a solution on my code that I posted? Thank you people very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a simpler method that I'm not aware of, but the following method should work:

Use NSNotificationCenter to post a notification back to the ViewController containing the UIPopOverController to tell it to dismiss the popover.

First, in ViewController.m viewDidLoad add:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(closePop:) name:@"ClosePopOver" object:nil];
```

Then add the following method to ViewController.m:

```
- (void)closePop:(NSNotification *)notification {
      [_firstPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Then in irstPopoverViewController.m:

```
- (void)closePop {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ClosePopOver" object:nil];        
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Now this is the easiest solution I've seen so far and it works like charm! Awesome, thank you very much.

Comment: but is this the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

A delegate is the way to go. I do admit though that I was confused by them at first, but they are quite simple to setup.

In your firstPopoverController.h put this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol FirstPopoverDelegate
- (void) closedPopover;
@end

@interface firstPopoverViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id< FirstPopoverDelegate > delegate;

@end
```

Then in your .m of you popover,

```
-(void)closePop 
{
     [self.delegate closedPopover];
}
```

In your main UIViewController's .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "firstPopoverViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <FirstPopoverDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *popButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) firstPopoverViewController *firstPopoverViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *firstPopover;

@end
```

Then in the .m, first register to listen of the delegate by adding this to your `openPop` method:

**this is important and easy to forget.. nothing will happen if it is not set**

```
_firstPopoverViewController.delegate = self;
```

Finally, in your .m add the delegate method:

```
- (void)closedPopover
{
    //you can also pass data back in this function, just modify its parameters here and when you define it in the .h of the popover 
    [_firstPopoverViewController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I wanted, but it doesn't work, I don't know why. I did exactly what you said, but it doesn't trigger closedPopover method. I've got NSLog in closePop and this function triggers, but closedPopover doesn't trigger (I've got NSLog here as well). It doesn't display any error when I build it. Only one thing I changed: [_firstPopoverViewController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; to [_firstPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; (it was throwing an error)